# How to Re-Install Windows 7 on Sony Vaio Laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, sony-vaio

I have Sony Vaio Laptop with Windows 7. Now I am only seeing Black screen even in Safe mode. How to re-install Windows 7

Comment: You should have received a bunch of DVDs for restoring your laptop - **otherwise** you have been asked to create a restore media after booting it for the first time.

Comment: I don't have any DVD

Comment: RTFM ;) There is often a key combination you have to press at boot to start the Restore to the factory default image.

Comment: @magicandre1981 what is the key combination?

Comment: sorry i have no idea, look into the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-installing windows is really simple, you only need your original drivers which you can download from Sony's website.
[Here's microsoft's guide.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/installing-and-reinstalling-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Vaio has `Assist` Button and if you press the Assist Button and follow the instructions it will restore the whole system at factory setting. Make a backup of important data because it will remove all the files from the Hard drive.